# In keras how to get epoch and validation loss from model checkpoint?

Tags: keras

From here (https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) you can save the best model according to the validation error by setting save_best_only.

I know you can save the corresponding epoch and validation error by writing it to the checkpoint's file name. However, this means a lot of models could be saved and I expect this to result in memory error on my GPU.

Is there a way to get the epoch and val loss corresponding to the final best model without having to write it in the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the epoch and validation error and at what time in the training, but you can implement your own callback functionality quite easily. What you want to get the training metrics is the `logs` object, which is passed to the callback in each of the callback events (see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L185)).

If for example you need to call a certain function f with the epoch and validation error at the end of every epoch, you could implement this using the `LambdaCallback`:

```
keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: f(epoch, logs['val_loss']))
```

If instead you want to use the ModelCheckpoint callback but don't want it to write to file, you can create a custom CallBack that rewrites the ModelCheck callback and changes the save behavior (code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L444)).

(Don't know if that answers your question, not entirely sure what the requirements are)